# Flutter - Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath

Tags: android, flutter

I build an android app with flutter to show user location, but I got this error after add geolocator: '^4.0.0' dependencies on pubspec.yaml, I have tried other suggestions but it still doesn't work...

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath. You should manually set the same version via DependencyResolution
```

on android/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                details.useVersion "26.1.0"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

on android/app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.salesman"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

help, what is wrong? thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Android dependency 'androidx.core:core' has different version for the
>   compile (1.0.0) and runtime (1.0.1) classpath. You should manually set
>   the same version via DependencyResolution

You should try with

- Change **`gradle`** version from 3.2.1 to 3.3.1/ 3.3.2

**DEMO**

```
dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        }
```

If same problem coming then add

```
 subprojects {
        project.configurations.all {
            resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                    details.useVersion "27.1.1"
                }

                if (details.requested.group == 'androidx.core'
                        && !details.requested.name.contains('androidx') ) {
                    details.useVersion "1.0.1"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, you should change /android/build.gradle file to new version as below:

ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.0'

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'

Answer (score 0):

Your project seems to not be configured to use AndroidX, from what the build.gradle looks like. See https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate for details. There is a menu option under "Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX" for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

1.Go to build.gradle under gradle folder and change the classpath dependancies to

```
buildscript {
     repositories {
          google()
           jcenter()
 }

 dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.1'
  }
}
```

2. Go to android->gradle->wrapper->gradle-wrapper.properties and change the distribution URL to

   ```
   distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.1.1-all.zip
   ```